# Windows form application - C# Random numer guessing game

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I need a little help with a Random Number Guessing Game in visual studio.  I got the brunt of the code down but I am having troubles with the Random number generator and getting the random number to port into the click events.  As always, I don't really need code but some guidance and/or explanations as to what I am doing wrong and if there is a more effecient way to do things in the beginner phases of learning.  Below is my code, the comments are the parts where I am having troubles.  Thanks for any help as the help I've recieved to date as been phenominal.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LAB6B
{
    public partial class game : Form
    {
        public game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Generate Random number between 1 and 100
         //Not sure if there is a better way?
            Random rand1 = new Random();
            int num1 = rand1.Next(1,50);
            int num2 = rand1.Next(1,50);
            int answer = num1 + num2;

        }

        private void evaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int choice = Convert.ToInt32(guess);


            if (guess.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                // set counter to keep track of how many tries
                // should this be done by a loop or will it count without a loop?
                count++;

                //compare user input against random number
          //Can’t import the random number for comparision
                if (choice < answer)
                {
                    Evaluate.Visible = false;
                    lblMessage.Visible = true;
                    lblMessage.Text = "Too Low!";
                    Clear.Visible = true;
                    BackColor = Color.LightSeaGreen;
                }
                else if (choice > answer)
                {
                    Evaluate.Visible = false;
                    lblMessage.Visible = true;
                    lblMessage.Text = "Too High!";
                    Clear.Visible = true;
                    BackColor = Color.SlateBlue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Display correct message along with how many times it took to get it
                    MessageBox.Show(" Eso es CORRECTO! It took you {0} tries. ", count);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            guess.Text = "";
            Evaluate.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Visible = false;
            Clear.Visible = false;
            BackColor = Color.PowderBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `rand1` and `answer` variables are defined within the constructor, you can only access them in the constructor. Defining `answer` on the class level will solve most of the problems, as you will be able to access it both from the constructor and the click handlers, like this:

```
private int answer;
private int count;

public game()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  //Generate Random number between 1 and 100
  Random random= new Random();
  // no need for num1 and num2, it's just as random
  answer = random.Next(1,101);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  This will help greatly and the random looks easier.  The one I had used was an example that I found.  I actually found three of them, each a little different.  I'm under the impression that Random() is clock based and at time can produce the same results over and over again, which is why i tried the one in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue of scope. The "answer" variable is declared inside your constructor, so it will not be visible to the code inside evaluate_Click(…).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to declare `answer` as a class variable. When you declare a variable in a constructor, it's still local to that method and not available to other methods.

Comment: I had a funny feeling it was something like that but wasnt' sure.  Thank you for the quick reply and the great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know what you want answered, but an obvious error is that you must define your `count` variable as a member variable in order to keep track of the number of tries. As it is now, the `count` will always be initialized as zero each time the user presses the button.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was one of the things I was working on/stumped by.  And thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

First of, you need to declare your variable `answer` in the page level so it can be used by other page level functions.

Do it like this

```
public partial class game : Form
    {
        int answer;
        public game()
        {
        }
    }
```

in your counter you can use a static counter or a page level variable also such as the variable `answer`

just reset the counter when the user have guessed correctly